# GNSDK identify PCM stream

Tags: java, audio

I am new to the GNSDK and try to get informations about a PCM stream.
I downloaded the GNSDK and I also have the Java libraries imported, however, I don't understand the documentation.
Could someone help me how I can receive the response object for a PCM stream of audio?

Thanks a lot.